# Get the last matching key from an array of objects to check value

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Where my data looks like so:

```
[
 {
  _id:1
  events: [
   {selectedPet: 'cat', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:00.000Z'},
   {selectedPet: 'dog', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:01.000Z'},
   {colourHat: 'green', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:01.200Z'},
   {selectedPet: 'bird', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:02.000Z'},
  ]
 },
 {
  _id:2
  events: [
   {selectedPet: 'bird', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:00.000Z'},
   {selectedPet: 'cat', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:01.000Z'},
   {selectedPet: 'dog', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:02.000Z'},
   {favouriteAnimal: 'bird', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:04.000Z'},
  ]
 }
]
```

How can I query for the last selected pet (last in the array, or last by time - array is chronological) being a bird?

Doing:

```
db.getCollection('events').find({
   'events.selectedPet': 'bird'
});
```

Will return both documents, but the intended output for selecting documents where the last select pet was a bird would be:

```
[
 {
  _id:1
  events: [
   {selectedPet: 'cat', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:00.000Z'},
   {selectedPet: 'dog', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:01.000Z'},
   {colourHat: 'green', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:01.200Z'},
   {selectedPet: 'bird', time: '2015-09-18T12:00:02.000Z'},
  ]
 }
]
```

This is example data. My real data set is hundreds of thousands of documents each with around 500 events.

Thank you =)

Comment: I am not sure what is the expected result. Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32651664/edit) to show the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. But bear in mind that it does JavaScript evaluation and [cannot take advantage of indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations).

```
db.collection.find({ "$where": function() { 
    for (var i = this.events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        if (this.events[i]["selectedPet"]) { 
            return this.events[i]["selectedPet"] === "bird"; 
        }
    }}
})
```

From forthcoming release you can use aggregation and the `$slice` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {
            "e": { "$slice": [
                { "$setDifference": [ 
                    { "$map": { 
                        "input": "$events", 
                        "as": "ev", 
                        "in": { "$ifNull": ["$$ev.selectedPet", false]}
                    }}, 
                    [false]]
                }, 
               -1
            ]}, 
            "events": 1
     }}, 
     { "$match": { "e": "bird" } }
])
```

Comment: Not having indexes would be awful. It looks like using your approach if I were to ask for 'dog' it would not return document number 2, even though document 2's last selectedPet was a dog.

Comment: @Drew edited my answer. But you need to use `$where` here.